nginx error - (2: No such file or directory) when making req through frontend
In an ubuntu server I have two versions of a node.js + express & reactjs app , one for test and another for prod. Their path is something like (sorry for the bad representation. Tell me if you have any sugestion to make it better):
/home/usr/app_name/[test or prod]/client/index.html;

/home/usr/app_name/[test or prod]/client/assets/(index.js & index.css);

/home/usr/app_name/[test or prod]/server/(config & dist & node_modules & package.json & package-lock.json);

First my node app served the static files using express, but since I'm implementing HTTPS to it, I decided to use nginx as reverse proxy and web server. My idea is to have nginx listening on a port, serving my static files and forwarding the reqs to my node api. When the user reach "uri", it must serve the prod files and "uri/test" must serve the test files, so I defined the following on my sites-available and linked to sites-enabled:
server {
    listen 3000 ssl;
    listen [::]:3000;
    
    server_name my_domain www.my_domain;

     ssl_certificate /path/to/ssl_certificate.crt;
     ssl_certificate_key /path/to/private/ssl_private_key.key;
    
    location / {
        alias /home/usr/app_name/prod/client/dist;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @backend_prod;
    }

    location @backend_prod {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    
  location /test {
        alias /home/usr/app_name/test/client/dist;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @backend_test;
    }

    location @backend_test {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

Before I was using root instead of alias, but nginx was passing /test as part of my path, so I got an error about it request to /test/assets/index. With the config I provided above, I was getting:

2024/04/18 15:52:05 [error] 34477#34477: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/assets/index-f38f2b09.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: IP, server: my_domain, request: "GET /assets/index-f38f2b09.js HTTP/1.1", host: "my_domain:5000", referrer: "https://my_domain:5000/test/"

And on browser it gives me a Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway).
I found two ways to solve it. Adding:
location /assets {
    alias /home/usr/app_name/test/client/dist/assets;
}

Or changing try_files $uri $uri/ @backend_test; to try_files $uri $uri/ index.html; and changing location @backend_test { to location /api {.
Now I'm stuck in another problem. That's an example of req my client do:
await fetch("/api/users/me", {
        method: "GET",
        credentials: "include",
     });

And that's how my server side handle it:
app.ts:
private router(): void {
    this.app.use("/", routes);
    this.app.use(handleAllErrors);
  }

routes.ts:
router.get(
  "/api/users/me",
  authenticate,
  userController.getMe.bind(userController)
);

I removed the authenticate and did a get using curl and it returned the expected, but when I do with nginx, I get stuck on:

2024/04/18 15:57:10 [error] 35226#35226: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/api/users/me" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: IP, server: my_domain, request: "GET /api/users/me HTTP/1.1", host: "my_domain:5000", referrer: "https://my_domain:5000/test/"

I tried:

Changing the server side location to location /api { or location /test/api {, but I continue getting the same error;

I also tried testing location / { and it returns nginx html instead of my files;

I have already used chmod +x to give the necessary permission into the path to my static files;

I tried puting the location /api {, location /test/api { and location @backend_test { inside the location /test {; Changing proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000; to proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/; but it says:



nginx: [emerg] location "/api" is outside location "/test" in
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my_domain:30 nginx: configuration
file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed


I tried changing location @backend_test { to location @backend_test/ { or proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000; to proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;, but it says:


nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my_domain


After some tests, I re-enabled my nodejs server to serve my static files and tried to use nginx only as reverse proxy, but I found another problem: It proxies correctly when I configure to http by removing ssl from listen 3000 ssl; and commenting ssl_certificate/path/to/ssl_certificate.crt; ssl_certificate_key/path/to/private/ssl_private_key.key; , but when I configure https, it only shows nginx index.html with "Welcome to nginx...";

Thank you in advance and sorry for any grammatical error!!
